# How to combine environment variables and bracket expansion in strings in Linux Bash?

Tags: bash

I'd like to write a bash script that would create a directory structure like this:

```
foo
 | - innerdir1
 | - innerfile1
```

This action should be repeated multiple times for different directory foo names. Each foo name consists of two parts. So I guess I first need to set environment variables:

```
    $BAR=something
    $BAZ=anotherthing
```

And then I need to use them in a script that would produce the mentioned structure with foo's name like $BAR.$BAZ, i.e. something.anotherthing. How do I write such a script?

Answer (score 2):

```
for BAR in abc def
do
    for BAZ in ghi jkl mno
    do
        mkdir -p "$BAR.$BAZ/innerdir1"
        touch "$BAR.$BAZ/innerfile1"
    done
done
```

will create:

```
abc.ghi
 | - innerdir1
 | - innerfile1
abc.jkl
 | - innerdir1
 | - innerfile1
abc.mno
 | - innerdir1
 | - innerfile1
def.ghi
 | - innerdir1
 | - innerfile1
def.jkl
 | - innerdir1
 | - innerfile1
def.mno
 | - innerdir1
 | - innerfile1
```

Answer (score 0):

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$BAR" -o -z "$BAZ" ]; then
  echo "This script needs environment variables $BAR and $BAZ to be set."
  exit 1 
fi

dir=$BAR.$BAZ
mkdir $dir
mkdir $dir/innerdir1
touch $dir/innerfile1
```

Invoke as:

```
BAR=bar BAZ=baz ./script.sh
```

This will create: `bar.baz/innerdir1` and `bar.baz/innerfile1`.

Comment: good idea - but it needs to have $BAR and $BAZ set - it would be better to test these values before starting mkdir. e.g. if [ -n $BAR ]

Comment: @Andreas: The invocation shown sets those values. However, the script will fail and try to create the `.` directory if they're not set - so you're correct - the script should include some tests.

Comment: @Dennis, @Andreas: fixed

Comment: Now that tests for `$BAR` and `$BAZ` to not exist as files. It says "if there's a file with the name contained in `$BAR` *and* a file with the name contained in `$BAZ` then issue an error." The test should be `[ -z "$BAR" -o -z "$BAZ" ]` to test whether the variables have values.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

A simple start would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

# define foo array
FOOLIST=()

# can be repeated

# create foonames
BAR="something"
BAZ="anotherthing"

# add to foolist
FOOLIST+=("${BAR}.${BAZ}")

BAR="somethingnew"
FOOLIST+=("2${BAR}.${BAZ}")

BAR="somethingnewer"
FOOLIST+=("3${BAR}.${BAZ}")

# create folders from list
for folder in ${FOOLIST[@]}
do
        mkdir $folder
        mkdir $folder/innerdir1
        mkdir $folder/innerfile1
done
```

Comment: You can add items to an array more simply like this: `array+=(item)`

Comment: You're right - this is easier...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of environment variables, pass your names as arguments and write the script to use these arguments -- that would make a more flexible tool.

Lookup '`getopts`' at [this bash-guide page](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html) and other places.